# Loop through all tables in a database and insert a row based on the column data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, cursor

I want to be able to loop through all of the tables in my database and find out the each table data type and length. the If the data type is int , I have to insert 0 to that column , If the  column is String and length is less than 30 , insert 'UKN' or  If the  column is String and grater than 30 insert as 'UnKnown'.

How do i write a script that loops through all tables and insert in a database based on the condition?
For the particular table how to take every columns and related data type and check?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `information_schema.columns` system view, no need to for dreaded `CURSOR`

```
USE <DATABASE_NAME>
GO

SELECT C.TABLE_CATALOG
     , C.TABLE_SCHEMA
     , C.TABLE_NAME
     , C.COLUMN_NAME
     , C.DATA_TYPE
     , C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    , CASE
        WHEN C.DATA_TYPE = 'int' THEN '0' 
        WHEN C.DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') 
        THEN 
            CASE
                WHEN C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <30 then 'UKN' 
                ELSE 'UnKnown' 
            END 
        END 'OUTPUTFROM'
FROM
    information_schema.columns  C
ORDER BY 
    TABLE_NAME
```

To INSERT

```
;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT C.TABLE_CATALOG
         , C.TABLE_SCHEMA
         , C.TABLE_NAME
         , C.COLUMN_NAME
         , C.DATA_TYPE
         , C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
        , CASE
            WHEN C.DATA_TYPE = 'int' THEN '0' 
            WHEN C.DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') 
            THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <30 then 'UKN' 
                    ELSE 'UnKnown' 
                END 
            END 'OUTPUTFROM'
    FROM
        information_schema.columns  C
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE 
    ( database_name, table_schema, table_name, column_name, Output_from)
SELECT
    TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, OUTPUTFROM
FROM 
    cteX X
```

to UPDATE

```
;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT C.TABLE_CATALOG
         , C.TABLE_SCHEMA
         , C.TABLE_NAME
         , C.COLUMN_NAME
         , C.DATA_TYPE
         , C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
        , CASE
            WHEN C.DATA_TYPE = 'int' THEN '0' 
            WHEN C.DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') 
            THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <30 then 'UKN' 
                    ELSE 'UnKnown' 
                END 
            END 'OUTPUTFROM'
    FROM
        information_schema.columns  C
)
UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.OUTPUTFROM = X.OUTPUTFROM
FROM 
    dbo.TABLE T
INNER JOIN 
    cteX X ON   X.TABLE_CATALOG = T.database_name 
            AND X.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.table_schema
            AND X.table_name = T.table_name
            AND X.column_name = T.column_name
```

Comment: How to insert the 'OUTPUTFROM' values for those tables columns?

Comment: Please show what the table that want to INSERT into looks like

Comment: Not sure what you table looks like but I've updated the answer to show possible options to INSERT or UPDATE

Comment: In your script return all the columns from all tables . i want to insert the one row for all tables with 0 and 'Unknow' values which i have in the database.

Comment: Actual scenario is in my data warehouse database i have to insert 1st row as Known values for all  dimension tables not for fact tables. bcz i have more than 100 dimension tables in my data warehouse . so cant manually  run the script many.

Comment: Why is CURSOR "Dreaded" ? It's the perfect solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Use the system tables:

```
select    t.name as TableName
        , c.name as ColumnName
        , ty.name as [DataType]
        , case  when ty.name = 'int' then '0' 
                when ty.name in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') 
                    then case   when c.max_length <30 then 'UKN' 
                                else 'UnKnown' end 
           end as OUTPUT
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types ty on ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
where t.type = 'U'
```